# How to clear RequestQueue cache in Android Studio?

Tags: android

RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

**requestQueue.getCache().clear();**

I am performing above function to **clear cache** but it is not clearing. is there any other way to clear or permanently disable request queue cache ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try your own RequestQueue method for adding requests:

```
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(final Request<T> req, Context context, String tag) {
        req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                30000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        req.setShouldCache(false);
        req.setTag(tag);
        getRequestQueue(context).add(req);
    }
```

Allows you to specify more than just cache settings for a call (like the retry policy and tags for debugging). Not sure if this is what you are looking for?